# Rust or C++ for computational statistics?

Tags: bayesian, markov-chain-montecarlo, computational-statistics

I'll work on developing computer-intensive Bayesian sampling algorithms for spatio-temporal applications (e.g. MCMC, KF). So far, I'm thinking of coding my algorithms in C++. However, I've heard that Rust is becoming popular within the scientific computing community. Would you recommend Rust over C++ and why/why not? Or for the matter, which language would you recommend for developing statistical computing algorithms?

Comment: +1 but before starting this endeavour, is there a reason why the existing probabilistic programming languages (e.g. PyMC, Stan, Pyro, TensorFlow Probability, etc.) do not fit your use case? I am saying this as a person who worked with someone who pretty much made his own PPL for KFs only to realise 9 months in that using an existing PPL was faster computationally, easier to debug and easier for other people to use.

Comment: Neither of the languages was designed for the problem, there are general-purpose languages, which makes the question quite opinion-based. Why can't you just the existing software? Why are you limiting yourself between the two languages? There's, for example, Julia which was designed for problems like this and would already have a lot of it implemented.

Comment: just want to mention the existince of Rcpp https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/index.html

Comment: Tim, I'm not limiting myself to these two, I'm open to other choices as well. But my supervisor and some colleagues work with C++, so it makes sense to follow their lead.

Comment: user11852, I guess I haven't looked deep enough into PyMC and Stan to conclude that they are not flexible enough for my use case. As my goal is to develop algorithms and not only to apply existing ones, I thought I needed something more general. But I'll take your advice and do some research.

Comment: could you clarify what exactly you will work on? Stan has a generic "fixed" Hamiltonian MCMC scheme (https://mc-stan.org/docs/reference-manual/hmc-algorithm-parameters.html), and you write your model in "stan" which gets converted into C++ code.  You have libararies in R which build on stan for these models eg https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bmstdr/vignettes/bmstdr-vig_bookdown.html

Comment: I'm just starting my research, so I'm not sure at this point. But I believe that the goal is to (try to) find new ways of sampling, or work on tweaking existing ones, not only to apply known sampling methods currently implemented in existing packages.

Comment: @antarctica: Don't reinvent the wheel. (I saw your question on Reddit too.) Unless you are expecting to code a new sampler out of scratch, I would *strongly* advise against a low level language. Note that it is not just "the sampling" bit you are interested. If you have to write up all the utilities to assess convergence, chain properties, etc. etc. the endeavour opens up considerably. Also, auto-differentiation is a *huge* perk, writing ADVI by hand for example *without* autodiff is almost penance. (I will write a bit more on Reddit actually...)

Comment: Saw your answer on reddit too :) Good. thanks

Comment: @usεr11852 Could you share the reddit post?

Comment: @Galen: https://www.reddit.com/r/statistics/comments/10p3mgl/ << The thread is here.